# jquery onload .click() not working

Tags: jquery, onload

I have an click() function that should trigger when the page loads.
but it doesn't - only when you manually click it.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/serw5/

```
//onload: 
$(".pageselector").first().trigger('click');

$(".pageselector").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var pageid = $(this).data('pageid');
   alert(pageid);
   // ajax....
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r8cSA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `trigger` call after your handler declaration:

```
$(".pageselector").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageid = $(this).data('pageid');
    alert(pageid);
      // ajax....
});

$(".pageselector").first().trigger('click');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/serw5/1/

Answer (score 5):

You need to be put your `trigger` call after you bind the click handler. Right now, you are trying to trigger a non-existent click handler.